# The filename http://working.knights.co.in/uploads/retailer/demo.xlsx is not readable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, phpexcel

I try to read and fetch data from excel sheet using phpexcel in  Codeigniter.
but I get the error The **filename http://working.abc.co.in/abc/zyx/demo.xlsx is not readable**

#### Controller code

```
public function index()
{       
    $this->load->view('admin/welcome_message');
}

function import2(){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"], "abc/xyz/". $_FILES["file_name"]["name"]);

    $file_path=base_url("abc/xyz/".$_FILES["file_name"]["name"]);           

    @chmod($file,0777);
    $this->load->library('Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader');
    $this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->read($file);    
    $sheets=$this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->sheets[0];
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $excelarray = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->$sheets['numRows']; $i++) {
        $excelarray['name'] = $sheets['cells'][$i][1];
        $excelarray['phone'] = $sheets['cells'][$i][2];
    }

    print_r($excelarray);
    $this->load->view('super_admin/welcome_message');
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the full error message you're getting and point out where in your code it's thown?

Comment: Btw, you're storing the file path in `$file_path` (which you never use) but are then using an undefined variable `$file` later in your code.

Comment: base_url() does not work for this, it generates a URL https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that one of the problems is the $file_path variable, which is later on referenced to as $file. The `chmod($file,0777);` command is not able to process URLs, so it needs a local file path. Probably, the same problems appear in the `$this->spreadsheet_excel_reader->read($file);` line. Try populating the $file variable using `$file = FCPATH."/abc/xyz/".$_FILES["file_name"]["name"];`.

Comment: I change this variable ($file_path->$file) but not working